# Dataset has duplicate records

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting excel file data in dataset, but in dataset data is duplicate, excel file has four records and dataset is showing me 8 records. Each record is duplicate. My file extension is .xlsx.
What wrong i am doing?

Here is my code:

```
  public static DataSet GenerateExcelData(string path)
   {
       OleDbConnection oledbConn = null;
       try
       {

           /* connection string  to work with excel file. HDR=Yes - indicates 
              that the first row contains columnnames, not data. HDR=No - indicates 
              the opposite. "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" 
              (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. 
           Note that this option might affect excel sheet write access negative. */

           if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xls")
           {
               oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
           }
           else if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xlsx")
           {
               //oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
               oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
           }
           oledbConn.Open();
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); ;
           OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();

           cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
           oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
           oleda.Fill(ds);
           //EDIT: Below lines are duplicate
           //oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
           //oleda.Fill(ds);
           return ds;
       }
       // need to catch possible exceptions
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
       finally
       {
           oledbConn.Close();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are filling the dataset twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
oleda.Fill(ds);
```

Why is this block of code repeated twice? I think this is causing the error

Answer (score 1):

You are filling your dataset twice.

```
 oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 oleda.Fill(ds);

 oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 oleda.Fill(ds);
```

You might forgot that you already added that two lines. You just need to delete the duplicate code.